# Is '<<-' operator not able to define a variable?

Tags: r

In the following function I saw somewhere as an example, variable `m` is first defined as NULL using the usual assignment operator `<-`.

Later, in the function `set()`, `m` is initialized as `NULL` using the new assignment operator `<<-` in line 5. It results in `m` becoming a global variable with value `NULL`.

I do not understand why we had to define it first using the usual assignment operator as well in line 2.

```
makeVector <- function(x = numeric()) {
        m <- NULL
        set <- function(y) {
                x <<- y
                m <<- NULL
        }
        get <- function() x
        setmean <- function(mean) m <<- mean
        getmean <- function() m
        list(set = set, get = get,
             setmean = setmean,
             getmean = getmean)
}
```

Comment: It is generally considered a VeryBadIdea(TM) to modify variables outside the current environment.  This action is not allowed in any submission to CRAN.  If you want to access `m`, better to do it by creating a specific environment  for your objects and accessing that as needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't define `m` it will be created in the global environment rather than in the function.  From `?"<<-"`

> The operators ‘<<-’ and ‘->>’ are normally only used in functions, and
> cause a search to be made through parent environments for an existing
> definition of the variable being assigned.  If such a variable is
> found (and its binding is not locked) then its value is redefined,
> otherwise assignment takes place in the global environment.  Note that
> their semantics differ from that in the S language, but are useful in
> conjunction with the scoping rules of R.  See ‘The R Language
> Definition’ manual for further details and examples.

Here is a small example that illustrates firstly that `m` is predefined in `f` so when `g`, defined in `f`, writes to `m` the variable `m` in `f` is the one that is changed whereas in `f2` the variable `m` is not predefined anywhere so it gets set in the global environment.

```
# Case 1. m is predefined in f

if (exists("m")) rm(m)
f <- function() {
   m <- 0
   g <- function() m <<- 1
   g()
   m
}
f()
## [1] 1
exists("m")
## [1] FALSE

# Case 2. m is not predefined

f2 <- function() {
   g <- function() m <<- 1
   g()
   m
}
f2()
## [1] 1
m # m defined in global environment
## [1] 1
```